# How to use an instance with type of union of interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider following TypeScript code:

```
class A {public name: string = 'A';}
interface B {num: number;}

class Foo {
    get mixed(): Array<A | B> {
        const result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
            result.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? new A() : {num: 42});
        }
        return result;
    }

    print(): string {
        return this.mixed.map(item => {
            if (item instanceof A) {
                return item.name;
            }

            return item.num;    
        }).join('\n');
    }
}
```

Inside the `print` function, I need to return different values based on type of the `item`. For type `A`, it's easy to use `instanceof`, but for `B` I can't use `instanceof` because `B` is an interface.

TypeScript does not understand that in the line that it says `item.num`, `item` is type `B` for sure and there is no need to complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
return (<B>item).num;
```

to give a hint to the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: That works in my example, but how you do it in TSX? `<B>` will get compiled as an HTML tag

Comment: You can use `as` operator: `let b = item as B; return b.num;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition, another way can be to use [user defined type guard functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1007)

So, you can have something like

```
  class A ...
  interface B ...
  function isB(item: any): item is B {
      return item && 'num' in item;
  }

  class Foo {...
     print(): string {
         return this.mixed.map(item => {
            if (item instanceof A) {
              return item.name;
            } else if(isB(item)){
              return item.num;
            }  
    }).join('\n');
  }..
```